# facebook_business.exceptions.FacebookBadObjectError: Bad data to set object data error when trying to pull advertiser data

Tags: python, facebook, ads

I am trying to pull advertiser data from facebook ads api but getting the following error in python -

```
facebook_business.exceptions.FacebookBadObjectError
```

does this have anything to do with the access token? or is something wrong with the facebook_business library itself?

Can someone help with what this means?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with 16.0.0, updating to 17.0.2 seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolved this or found a workaround?

I have had the same issue since the same day, so I think it's an issue on facebook's end when using their cursor object to a certain length.  No matter what data set I pull, it errors out when it hits 10475 objects. This was not an issue until June 14th.

Comment: it was a bug from the facebook api side. they fixed it a couple dayes after